# get certain elements on the page PHP Gallery

Tags: php, jquery, html

So I'm tinkering away with a CMS called The Secretary because it's mostly been very easy to mess around with. There's a large problem with one of its components, however, that I really can't put my finger around because I just started learning PHP, and no one's answering any questions in the forum.

The code that was provided is supposed to generate thumbnails from a certain folder. On the page itself, when you click the thumbnail, the actual image should pop up, kind of like a very basic lightbox. But all the code does is generate the thumbnails. When you click the thumbnails, nothing happens.

The codes:
http://pastebin.com/879XpcFU (pop.plugin.php)

http://pastebin.com/CS3k6uXF (pop.js)

I don't really want to touch it anymore, so I was thinking of just using jQuery to load an image based on two things: the source of the thumbnail, and the the id on the link of the page.

So if the page is: mydomain com/?projects=project-slug
and the url of the thumbnail is at mydomain com/files/cache/picture.50x50.jpg
it would show the image at mydomain com/files/projects/project-slug/picture.jpg

Is that possible with jQuery? If not, what do I change to the PHP code above to make this work? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Press F-12, open the JavaScript Console. Look for errors. Work from there.

Comment: @Diodeus I get a `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: popper` but popper is a class. But then on the JS file it shows as a function.

Comment: It could be that you're calling popover before it is initialized. This is a 100% client-side issue. It has nothing to do with PHP, so you really need to show your rendered HTML page in your pastebin. The PHP just complicates things.